# How to import csv file into database and move into a folder using jquery ajax in codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, csv, mysqli, import

Views:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#upload_csv').on("submit",function(e){  
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    $.ajax({  
                         url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>import",  
                         method:"POST",  
                         data:new FormData(this),  
                         contentType:false, 
                         cache:false, 
                         processData:false,  
                         success: function(data){  
                              if(data=='Error1')  
                              {  
                                   alert("Invalid File");  
                              }  
                              else if(data == "Error2")  
                              {  
                                   alert("Please Select File");  
                              }  
                              else  
                              {  
                                   $('#success').html(data);  
                              }  
                         }  
                    })  
               });  
    });
</script>
<form id="upload_csv" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function import()
{
    if(!empty($_FILES["files"]["name"]))  
    {   
        $output = '';  
        $allowed_ext = array("csv");  
        $tmp = explode(".", $_FILES["files"]["name"]);  
        $extension = end($tmp);
        if(in_array($extension, $allowed_ext))  
        {  
            $file_data = fopen($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], 'r');  
            print_r(fgetcsv($file_data));

        }  
        else  
        {  
            echo 'Error1';  
        }  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo "Error2";  
    }  
}
```

In this code I want to import `csv file` in my database and also move csv file into a folder. Now, What actually happen when I click on submit button I am using `print_r(fgetcsv($file_data));` to know the output of csv file then it print

```
Array ( [0] => Id [1] => first_name [2] => last_name [3] => phone [4] => email )
```

but I have 200 rows in my csv file. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: did you read the docs ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php - you get one line because `fgetcsv` reads only one line from the current file pointer - you've to wrap your code in a `while` loop or something like that (thats exactly what you can see in the example section)

Answer (score 0):

at you function import

```
  public function import()
            {
                    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                    $config['allowed_types']        = 'csv';

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('files'))
                    {
                            print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                            EXIT;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    $fData = $this->upload->data();        
    $data = array();
    $file = fopen($fData['file_name'], "r");
             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {
                $data[] = array(
                'fieldname1' => $emapData[0];
                'fieldname2' => $emapData[1];
                );
    // array for active record 
             }
             fclose($file);
             $this->load->model('any_model');
             $this->any_model->batch_data($data);
             echo "CSV File has been successfully Imported.";

                    }
            }
    }
```

model:

```
function batch_data($data = array())
{
 $this->db->insert_batch('table_name',$data);
}
```

that are the steps you need to follow ...

Comment: I have got error @MasihAnsari i.e. `The upload path does not appear to be valid.`

Comment: create uploads folder at base path ... where you have your application folder and index.php file

Comment: I have already created a folder `FCPATH.'resource/csv';` @MasihAnsari

Comment: if you have created folder `'resource/csv'` so you have to set `$config['upload_path']` to `recourse/csv`